# Assign Card to a User by Default in Trello

Tags: trello, user-accounts

I have a project where I am working with just one developer. Every card is for him to review. Is there a way to have the cards for that project assigned to him by default? It is annoying to have to enter a task and then assign it to him each time.

I hope I'm just missing how this is done, as it seems like a basic feature (available in Fog Bugz).

Answer (score 2):

We are also working on board and list subscriptions. The developer will be able to subscribe to all new cards in a given list or board, thus getting notified.

FogBugz is a far more heavyweight product than Trello, directed at a technical audience, so probably not a good reference point for what's a basic feature or not.

Answer (score 0):

Trello is working on a way to [copy cards](https://trello.com/c/aFZlOp9o) to be used as template. When that is done, you can simply create an empty card with his name on it. When you want to create a new card, just copy that one.